# Rails mongoid - Access User with user_id present in another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have an app with many users, that can create many travels, and they can invite friends to participate to the travel.

Here are the models :

```
class Travel
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  belongs_to :user

  embeds_many :participants
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :participants
end

class Participant
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  # relations
  embedded_in :travel, :inverse_of => :participants

end
```

When I look my DB I have this result for participants : 
[image: screen DB]

It is embedded in travel.
Right now, I want to access user, thanks to the user_id that you see in the DB, on the travel page, but I don't know what request I have to write to implement that. I want to access users which are participants.

Does I have to use `.where()` like : `User.where(:id.in => ...)` or `.find_by()` .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Travel` and `User` are associated (`belongs_to`), you can call directly..

```
Travel.last.user
```

Or

```
User.where(id: Travel.participants.pluck(:user_id))
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, I want to access users that are invited in the travel (in the embedded document -> participant), when I do : `@travel.participant.last.user` I have this error : `undefined method `user' for #<Participant:0x007ffdaf6e0e88> Did you mean? user_id`, and I want to access all participants that are invited to the travel

Comment: Check update, I thought participant and user are associated..well..it should be

Comment: Thank buddy it work well, I didn't know `pluck`, it's perfect !

Comment: Do you know how to access to my user data ? When I use byebug, and show the result of pluck, I have this : `#<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"_id"=>[BSON::ObjectId('592c8da58511989ec850921e'), BSON::ObjectId('592c8da58511989ec850921e')]}`.. I don't know how to access datas

Comment: `pluck(:user_id)` gives you a list of `user_id`s..to access the `id` you probably can do `.first` on plucked result..